# Signal handler not found

Tags: perl

For some reason threads doesn't seem to be able to find the $SIG{'KILL') signal. I got the code from a comment here http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=557219 This is on Windows.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;

sub test_sub{
    $SIG{'KILL'} = sub { threads->exit(); };
    while(1){}  
}

my $new_thread = threads->create('test_sub');

$new_thread->kill('KILL')->detach();
```

returns

```
Signal KILL received in thread 1, but no signal handler set. at test1.pl line 13.
Perl exited with active threads:
        1 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

Edit: looks like I'm using threads version '1.43'. I don't know if that the problem but I'll try a newer version.

Comment: Signal is delivered to the process and I'd think that it's a global thing, only. Do you need it hidden in a thread?  You can use a (global) variable that you'd set in handler, but I don't see how that would help individual threads.

Comment: Hmm. I guess not but what if I had a different thread that I wanted to do some cleanup on a KILL signal?

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: hm, your code's right out of docs, I didn't realize that. I can confirm the behavior, on v5.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be some sort of race condition, and it works when there is more going on.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $thread_handler_on :shared = 0;

sub test_handler {
    say "\tIn thread.";
    $SIG{'KILL'} = sub {
        $thread_handler_on = 1;
        say "\tSet flag, exiting the thread in handler";
        threads->exit();
    };
    sleep 3;
    say "\tSet handler";
    sleep 1;
    say "\tHandler done napping";
}

my $new_thread = threads->create( 'test_handler' );

sleep 1;

say "Sending 'kill' to thread";
$new_thread->kill('KILL')->detach();

sleep 5;

say "Did handler run: $thread_handler_on";
```

The code in the question is right [out of threads](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#THREAD-SIGNALLING) docs (along with `detach`). 
This prints

```
        In thread.
Sending 'kill' to thread
        Set flag, exiting the thread in handler
Did handler run: 1
```

Without those `sleep`s in the main thread I also get the reported behavior.

Note that these "signals" *are not* sent via kernel, per [Threads signalling](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#THREAD-SIGNALLING)

> The thread signalling capability provided by this module does not actually send signals via the OS. It emulates signals at the Perl-level such that signal handlers are called in the appropriate thread.

Comment: I've hit problems like this before - it's because the 'kill' isn't actually a signal, it's a deferred safe-signal - that only happens when it's appropriate to process (so won't interrupt certain operations). Sleep is generally safe to interrupt with a handler.

Comment: @Sobrique Right, it's not the OS-delivered signal, which is why I included the quote and the link (there is way more there than what I quote). The problem though is due to race conditions, not signals themselves, as shown in detail in ikegami's answer. (There may not be such a problem with kernel signals -- is that what you mean? -- but that is moot, and we couldn't test it, since those can't go to a particular thread).

Answer (score 2):

There are not one but two race conditions that could lead to the behaviour you observe:

- You're sending the KILL signal before the child has a chance to setup the signal handler.

  Below, I used synchronization to ensure the signal handler is created before the signal is sent.
- You're exiting the program before the signal handler has a chance to call `threads->exit`.

  Why do people insist on using `->detach`?

Fixed:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub test_handler {
    say sprintf "[%s %s] Starting thread", time, threads->tid;
    say sprintf "[%s %s] Doing stuff", time, threads->tid;
    sleep 4;
    say sprintf "[%s %s] Done doing stuff", time, threads->tid;
    say sprintf "[%s %s] Exiting thread", time, threads->tid;
}

sub create_thread(&) {
   my ($thread_func) = @_;

   # Reap any threads that might have exited.
   $_->join() for threads->list(threads::joinable);

   my $ready :shared = 0;
   my $thread = async {
      $SIG{KILL} = sub {
         say sprintf "[%s %s] Forcibly exiting thread", time, threads->tid;
         threads->exit();
      };

      # Signal creator that the thread is initialized.
      { lock $ready; $ready = 1; cond_signal($ready); }
      $thread_func->();
   };

   # Wait for the thread to finish initializing.    
   { lock $ready; while (!$ready) { cond_wait($ready); } }
   return $thread;
}

my $thread = create_thread(\&test_handler);

say sprintf "[%s %s] Sending KILL signal", time, threads->tid;
$thread->kill('KILL');

say sprintf "[%s %s] Doing stuff", time, threads->tid;
sleep(2);
say sprintf "[%s %s] Done doing stuff", time, threads->tid;

# Wait for threads to exit.
say sprintf "[%s %s] Waiting for threads to exit", time, threads->tid;
$_->join() for threads->list();
say sprintf "[%s %s] Exiting", time, threads->tid;
```

Output:

```
[1513212149 1] Starting thread
[1513212149 1] Doing stuff
[1513212149 0] Sending KILL signal
[1513212149 0] Doing stuff
[1513212151 0] Done doing stuff
[1513212151 0] Waiting for threads to exit
[1513212153 1] Forcibly exiting thread
[1513212153 0] Exiting
```

**IMPORTANT** Note that the signal didn't interrupt `sleep`. No actual POSIX signal is sent<sup>[1]</sup> (since you can only send those to a process), so OS calls can't be interrupted. Instead, Perl actively checks if a signal was sent between most Perl opcodes<sup>[2]</sup>. But that means that long-running opcodes like `sleep`, `m//` and XS functions calls can delay the signal handler indefinitely.

---

1. That's fortunate for you, seeing as you're not using a POSIX system.
2. Some time ago, it used to be between each opcode, but the number of checks was reduced. I think Perl now checks once per statement.